# Magnetostatics analysis of Switched Reluctance Motor in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, modeling, electromagnetics

Accidentally stumbled upon magnetostatic calculation in Mathematica.

https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/nonlinear-finite-elements/magnetostatics.html?product=mathematica

I would like to ask a question to professionals:
Is it possible in Mathematica to write a program that forms the **2D** geometry of a switched-reluctance motor (size, number of phases, etc.), makes a magnetostatic calculation and takes characteristics (for example, the dependence of the phase inductance on the angle of rotation of the rotor)?

I invite to cooperation.

[image]

Comment: Though imm sure mma could do this but it wouldn‘t be an easy task or quick...it may be more quickly done if mma provides data to femm (http://www.femm.info/wiki/HomePage)...or femm to mma...

Comment: It is difficult to shape geometry in femm. There it is done rather clumsily. I hope for comfortable programming in Mathematica.

Comment: It's been a while since I used femm...but I think it's just a matter of learning to type in coordinates correctly? In mma it wouldn't be a lot different...How would you expect mma to generate boundries without knowing anything you have in mind...Maybe you could edit your question to be more specific on what you're looking for...as in, "I imaginea function f[[diameter,toothform, windings, whatever] := ... that will generate x, y, z that I can then add to this specific FEM calculation with these boundry conditions" If you're more specific, my interests been piqued.

Comment: But to be honest, software like femm, and Ansys electro already do this (even entire rotor/stator generation) already, and very very very well...reinventing this in mma is very much wheel inventing again.

Comment: I previously did this in Ansys RMXprt with a transfer to Ansys Maxwell. And you know what scares me away: the speed of the calculation, even though the program is installed on the university supercomputer. Due to some peculiarities, it is impossible to parallelize the calculation, and the calculation of one machine ~ 3 hours. If you have experience with these programs, we can try to cooperate. If you are interested, again.